# How do we force Angular to use the global CLI version (which is greater than the local)?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm getting `Your global Angular CLI version (1.5.. ) is greater than your local version ( 1.2.. ) . The local Angular CLI version is used. To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".`

I do not wish to suppress that warning and do want to use 1.5 instead.

What do I need to do so that there is no local version that's getting in the way?

Comment: To the dude or dudette, what's the reason for the down vote? Show the world that you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if you do want to use the latest version would be to upgrade your existing version in your actual packages.json file. Unless there are some other constraints not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Hugo, just for the curiosity. When I edit the packages.json (to make a change on the version info on the CLI), do I need to do something special such as `npm update` or `npm install` ( one more time ) or do we just edit the packages.json and then simply continue as business as usual; `ng serve`?

Comment: You have two options for this to happen. If you do npm install —save-dev @angular/cli it will install the latest version and update your packages.json. If you do it by hand, yes you need to run npm install so that your packages are updated locally.

Comment: Idid `npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli`. After this, I saw a bunch of warning messages such as `
npm WARN @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.` I also noticed the final line was: `up to date in 5.964s`. I thought I was done. However, when I did my next `ng serve`, I ended up again with this message: `Your global Angular CLI version (1.5.2) is greater than your local version (1.2.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.`. What do you think might be interfering? Those peer stuff warnings?

Comment: The solution to uninstall it’s not really a solution for me since any other package that depends on it my install an earlier version.  That’s why I suggested you install the same version as you current global or higher and save it in the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, how do you install the latest version and --save it in the package json in one shot?

Comment: You have two options. You either do npm install —save-dev or you do a npm install —save. On will show under the dev dependencies group on package json. The other will show under the dependencies group. For a more detailed idea have a quick look on the documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the local package

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

It will automatically use the Global Angular CLI

Comment: This does not seem to do it Nechar. Please see my comments I left for Hugo below.